# How to install Gnome 3.2 in Debian 8.7?

Tags: debian, gnome

I know Gnome 3.2 doesn't have a stable version for Debian but I still would like to install it and I haven't found any instruction on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome 3.2 is currently in **[testing (Stretch)](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome)**. As the name implies, the "testing" version of Debian is not as stable as, eh, "stable"!

That said, it is definitely a lot safer than running Debian unstable. The *easiest* way for you to install Gnome 3.2 would probably be to switch to testing. Or...

You *could* **[mix your repositories](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing)**, which I personally am not a fan of (can cause odd and unexpected behavior and migraine). But apparently not all share my concerns. That said; don't do this in a server. Just don't. But since you are looking for a desktop environment, I am guessing this is for a desktop computer.

### From the official Debian FAQ:

> **3.1 Which Debian distribution (stable/testing/unstable) is better for me?**
>
> The answer is a bit complicated. It really depends on what you intend
> to do. One solution would be to ask a friend who runs Debian. But that
> does not mean that you cannot make an independent decision. In fact,
> you should be able to decide once you complete reading this chapter.
>
> - If security or stability are at all important for you: install stable. period. This is the most preferred way.
> - If you are a new user installing to a desktop machine, start with stable. Some of the software is quite old, but it's the least buggy
>   environment to work in. You can easily switch to the more modern
>   unstable (or testing) once you are a little more confident.
> - If you are a desktop user with a lot of experience in the operating system and do not mind facing the odd bug now and then, or
>   even full system breakage, use unstable. It has all the latest and
>   greatest software, and bugs are usually fixed swiftly.
> - If you are running a server, especially one that has strong stability requirements or is exposed to the Internet, install stable.
>   This is by far the strongest and safest choice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than worry about Debian 8, 9.0 (Stretch) is just around the corner and is quite stable - It's my daily driver, and I'll be keeping it for a year anyway when it goes stable. Stretch has Gnome 3.22.2 and it's rock solid for me (since it's in freeze).